# Kubernetes Ingress Nginx Controller is Not Found

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Ingress Nginx controller is returning 404 Not Found for the React application. I narrowed it down to the React app because if I try to hit posts.com/posts, it actually returns the JSON list of existing posts, but for the frontend app it keeps showing
GET http://posts.com/ 404 (Not Found)

I looked to some other stackoverflow questions, to no avail unfortunately.

**ingress-srv.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "use"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: posts.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /posts/create
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: posts-clusterip-srv
                port:
                  number: 4000
          - path: /posts
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: query-srv
                port:
                  number: 4002
          - path: /posts/?(.*)/comments
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: comments-srv
                port:
                  number: 4001
          - path: /?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: client-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

**client-depl.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: client-depl
spec: 
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: client
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: client
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: client
          image: br/client
          imagePullPolicy: Always
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client-srv
spec:
  selector: 
    app: client
  ports: 
    - name: client
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

frontend **Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:alpine

ENV CI=true

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ ./ 

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**Logging the pod:**

```
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From               Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  11m   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/client-depl-f7cf996cf-cvh6m to minikube
  Normal  Pulling    11m   kubelet            Pulling image "br/client"
  Normal  Pulled     11m   kubelet            Successfully pulled image "br/client" in 42.832431635s
  Normal  Created    11m   kubelet            Created container client
  Normal  Started    11m   kubelet            Started container client
```

If you need any other logs, I will gladly provide them. Thanks.

Comment: Hi everyone, so the issue was a really dumb one - I actually set ```nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "use"``` instead of ```nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"```... After three days of checking through the documentation, I finally found it. If anyone encounters a similar problem - there you have it.

Answer (score 1):

In your yamls, there is a path "/?..." for handling the query parameters but this path will not receive traffic from "/" path as there is no prefix match. So you have to create a path "/" with type prefix to solve the issue. Then you can ignore current "/?..." path as it will match prefix with "/" path.

Please try this:

```
ingress-srv.yaml
__________________
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "use"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: posts.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: client-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
          - path: /posts/create
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: posts-clusterip-srv
                port:
                  number: 4000
          - path: /posts
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: query-srv
                port:
                  number: 4002
          - path: /posts/?(.*)/comments
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: comments-srv
                port:
                  number: 4001
          - path: /?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: client-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

Answer (score 1):

so the issue was a really dumb one - I actually set nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "use" instead of nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"... After three days of checking through the documentation, I finally found it. If anyone encounters a similar problem - there you have it.

Comment: thanks,if have a same problem visit this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic

Answer (score 0):

You have to add following rules in your spec

```
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: client-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

This matches all paths.

Reference - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#examples